What equations describe magnetization of ferromagnetic materials?
When magnetic field is applied to a ferromagnetic material it magnetizes. Internal spins would be reoriented and magnetic moment would stay even after the external field is removed.
Most sources just describe this physical fenomenon in general without equations.
What are the time-dependent equations that describe magnetization of ferromagnetic materials?

Have you had a look into spin models, like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_lattice_Ising_model ?

Are you familiar with the static equations of ferromagnetism?  Because I think that should be your starting point.  But either way, you can google "transient Jiles-Atherton" as a starting point.

For a microscopic picture you can use the Landau-Lifshitz-Gilbert equation.
